# Как в pandas посчитать процентное содержание количества значений?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня есть `DataFrame`, который содержит различные значения.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"data": [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3]})
```

Я хочу посчитать, сколько процентов от общих данных занимает каждое значение, то есть получить таблицу вида:

```
value | percent
_____________________
0     | 30 ( или 0.3)
1     | 40 ( или 0.4)
2     | 20 ( или 0.2)
3     | 10 ( или 0.1)
```

Я могу посчитать так:

```
# Добавляю еще одну колонку, чтобы нормально посчитать count()
df['column'] = 1
df2 = df.groupby('data').count()
df2['percent'] = df2['column'] / len(df.index)
```

И получаю искомое:

```
      column  percent
data                 
0          3      0.3
1          4      0.4
2          2      0.2
3          1      0.1
```

Однако, меня не покидает ощущение, что я все делаю не так. И подобные вопросы должны решаться намного проще. 
Подскажите, как лучше решить мою задачу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно использовать метод [GroupBy.size()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) - в этом случае не понадобится создавать новый столбец:

```
In [4]: df.groupby('data').size() / len(df)
Out[4]:
data
0    0.3
1    0.4
2    0.2
3    0.1
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

наверно неактуально, но я считаю так:

df['data'].value_counts(normalize=True)

Comment: добавьте больше деталей в ваш ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer